# cordova command failed with exit code enoent

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have installed fresh cordova by npm also create a project and android platform but when I try to install any plugin, It showing me "command failed with exit code enoent". I have checked variable path for npm. 
I saw some solution from stackoverflow but nothing work.
Please help me to solve this error

[image]

Comment: do one thing rm platform and add again by following command: 1) cordova platform rm android and for add 2) cordova platform add android and try again to add plugin

Comment: @Bubai try removing android platform, install plugin and re-add the android platform

Comment: same problem after follow your answer@ Naitik

Comment: after cordova create when I install plugin, It's installing successfully but after that same error is coming when am installing android platform @Gandhi

Comment: @Bubai try upgrading Cordova and platforns